# Size of a UILabel to avoid breaking words

Tags: ios, uilabel, size

How to calculate the size of a UILabel, where I do not want to break any of word in the text, keep some kind of proportion like 3:4 for the label or use always 3 lines and wider width, but don't break words. How can I do it?

Comment: sizeToFit doesn't help ?

Comment: Or you using autolayout?

Comment: `sizeToFit` not always works, i.e. word "tevekenyseg" will be broken into two line like "teveken"-"yseg", I need it in one line